# In Firebase how do I run C++ in functions?

Tags: c++, firebase

I want to run C++ code in the backend, so in functions. Does anyone know how?

The question is generic on purpose, because I do not care how the code is built or called.
My initial thought was calling a C++ lib in nodejs, using FFI. I am still working on it, but I want to explore other options.

Nevertheless, my searches always lead to C++ projects running on the client side, and that not what I am looking for.

If something is unclear, please ask.
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use only Javascript and Typescript in Firebase Cloud Functions. Though you get more options like python, go and a few more in GOOGLE Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Dharmaraj in the comments,

> As far as I know, you can use only Javascript and Typescript in
> Firebase Cloud Functions. Though you get more options like python, go
> and a few more in GOOGLE Cloud Functions.

the only available language (as standard) in Firebase Functions/Hosting is JavaScript (NodeJS) or TypeScript. There are a few ways out there that attempt to make languages such as PHP work, however I will not link any as I have never tried any.

Google Cloud does offer a server environment with languages such as Go, Python, PHP (potentially C++), as opposed to a serverless environment that Firebase Functions runs in. A serverless  environment means that code cannot automatically run in the backend and must be called via HTTP request, pub/sub or cron job.

Comment: Thanks Luka S. Whatever I find out I will post it following my initial question.
As a just joined member of stackoverflow, I would like to understand what I should have wrote differently, so that I do not receive negative points. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Nat0ne, I am a new user too! I am not entirely sure why you have been downvoted, potentially because there are very similar questions with answers elsewhere, including on the Firebase Docs at [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview). Hope this helps!